# Dropdown menu list click function remove the active text and add the selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having problem with Bootstrap 3.2.0 dropdown list. I want, when the user click the dropdown list then remove the active text and add the selected text to dropdown list.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown2" tabindex="1">
  <p class="pieces" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <a href="#">Select # of Pieces <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  </p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu upDropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     <li>5pc to 30pc</li>
     <li>30pc to 100pc</li>
     <li>100pc to 300pc</li>
     <li>300pc to 500pc</li>
     <li>500pc to 2000pc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This dropdown HTML code is work well in Bootstrap 3. I don't understand which JavaScript or jQuery function work for remove the "Select # of Pieces" and add the text from dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu.upDropdown li').click(function(){
    $('#selected_piece').html($(this).html());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown dropdown2" tabindex="1">
  <p class="pieces" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <a href="#"id="selected_piece">Select # of Pieces <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  </p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu upDropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     <li>5pc to 30pc</li>
     <li>30pc to 100pc</li>
     <li>100pc to 300pc</li>
     <li>300pc to 500pc</li>
     <li>500pc to 2000pc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could imagine for taking the text out of that dropdown and putting that text into some other element is by using JQuery selectors to select the currently selected text, as follows:

```
$('#example-dropdown').change(function() {
     var selectedText = $('#example-dropdown option:selected').text();

     $('#my-output-div').text("Select " + selectedText + " Number of Peices");
});
```

Where

```
#example-dropdown
```

Is your  or head of your dropdown, and

```
#my-output-div
```

Is where you want the output to be placed.

Comment: Note that this JQuery code should be placed in a $(document).ready(function(){});